# Remove item from an array Options - Mongodb

Tags: php, codeigniter, mongodb

How would you remove an array item from a mongodb field . For example , how do i remove guitar from the list of interest . Any PHP functions or approaches would help.

```
{

        "_id" : ObjectId("4d1cb5de451600000000497a"),           
        "name" : "dannie",  
        "interests" : [  
            "guitar",  
            "programming",           
            "gadgets",  
            "reading"  
        ]   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

unset($array['interests']['guitar']) if this is array in PHP

Answer (score 0):

you can use [unset()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unset.php) function for this task.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Actually it should be

```
$key = array_search('guitar', $array['interests']);
unset($array['interests'][$key]);
```

as guitar is not a key for interests.